# CAML query for null lookup field values

Tags: caml-query, lookup-column

I have a problem with filtering list items using CAML

I Have this list: Code - Text, Name - Text, Link - Text, Order No - Number, Parent - Lookup to this List.
I want to filter all items where Parent is not selected (i.e none)

Here is my CAML query but it's not giving the right solution:

```
string camlquery = String.Format(@"<where>
                                                <Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='Lookup'></Value></Eq>
                                                </where>
                                               <OrderBy>
                                                <FieldRef Name='Order No'></FieldRef>
                                                </OrderBy>
                                               ", this.MenuItemParentField);
```

> MenuItemParentField  it's the name of the lookup column MenuItemParentField="Parent"

What is going wrong with my caml query

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [IsNull Element (Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462425) instead of [Eq Element (Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479601)

```
string camlquery = String.Format(@"<where> 
                                     <IsNull><FieldRef Name='Parent' /></IsNull> 
                                   </where> 
                                   <OrderBy> 
                                     <FieldRef Name='Order No'></FieldRef> 
                                   </OrderBy> 
                                   ", this.MenuItemParentField);
```

Comment: What if you remove the OrderBy, thats not a right InternalName, sorry I didn't see that before

Comment: This is an old post, but it was the first result from a Google search. It DOES work, Milena, and you accepted it as the answer. I think you should remove the comment saying it isn't working, it is confusing to those of us who come here two years later.